# vector desctructor fails at _CrtIsValidHeapPointer

Tags: c++, vector, heap-corruption

I`m new to c++, need to use it just to create shell namespace extension for c# application.

I have next code:

```
#ifdef MAKEDLL
#  define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
//...
DLLEXPORT class NativeFtp
{
public:
    DLLEXPORT void Initialize(string uniqeId);
    DLLEXPORT vector<FTPSITEACCESS> GetSites();
} _NativeFtp;
//...
vector<FTPSITEACCESS> NativeFtp::GetSites()
{
    vector<FTPSITEACCESS> vec;

    FTPSITEACCESS st;
    st.SiteName = "ftp://10.20.3.251/";
    st.Password = "";
    st.Login = "";

    vec.push_back(st);

    return vec;
}
```

Other library:

```
STDMETHODIMP CShellFolderImpl::EnumObjects ( HWND hwndOwner, DWORD dwFlags,
                                             LPENUMIDLIST* ppEnumIDList )
{
    // Skipped

    vector<FTPSITEACCESS> ftpSites = m_ftp.GetSites();
    vector<char*> names;

    /*for(vector<FTPSITEACCESS>::iterator it = ftpSites.begin(); it != ftpSites.end(); ++it)   {
        //char* ch = new char[(*it).SiteName.size()+1];
        //ch[(*it).SiteName.size()] = '/0';
        //std::copy((*it).SiteName.begin(),(*it).SiteName.end(),ch);
        //names.push_back(strdup(ch)); //TODO:FREE
    }*/

    // Skipped

    return hr;
}
```

This code fails on `'return hr'` at `_CrtIsValidHeapPointer` that is called by destructor of vector.
I tried to make `NativeFtp::GetSites()` return `vector<FTPSITEACCESS>*` as well as 
`vector<FTPSITEACCESS*>*` and then delete it before `'return hr'`, but it fails the same way.

Comment: This will be a quick crash when the caller and callee don't use the same C runtime library.  Compiling with /MD and the exact same compiler version with the exact same settings is required.

Comment: Thank you, it works, but for debug I used /MDd.

Comment: C++ as usually shows the result of problem, not the reason, that is huge time penalty, comparing to c#.

Answer (score 1):

`FTPSITEACCESS` will be copied. The copy ctor is not shown, but my crystal ball tells me that it's broken.

If you're coming from C#, just use the `std::string` class in C++. `strdup` and `new[]` are primitive operations which make you responsible for memory management, and you really want to avoid that. The reason is, you don't need to write a copy ctor for a class if all members have a working copy ctor (and similarly for assignment and move). But if you have even a single `char*` member, you suddenly have to write all those. The `std::string` class has one main responsibility: to encapsulate a single `char*` and provide copy/move/assignment.